# VirtualBox - 64 bit OS on a 32 bit host - Pros and Cons

Tags: 64-bit, virtualbox, 32-bit

Is is possible to run a 64 OS in a virtual environment host that is 32 bit. Say for example, I am running Windows XP 32 bit. Would it be possible for me to run a 64bit OS using VirtualBox or VMWare. My processor is a 64bit processor with VT enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can run a 64-Bit guest on a 32-Bit host using VirtualBox.

Moreover, I have tested the performance of a 64-Bit guest system
on 64-Bit and 32-Bit hosts and for my specific loads there
is no significant difference.

Sure, 64-Bit guest on a 64-Bit host feel slightly faster, but
according to my measurements it's about 5% difference.

Just make sure you have enough memory on the host
(4GB total will be reported as 3.5 GB for a 32Bit XP).